# String of integer values contained in a varchar variable do not work in a HAVING...IN clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Here's an example of the statement in the stored procedure:

```
  SELECT @nDBNum = Num
    FROM Num_members
GROUP BY Num
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Part_No IN (@strOrderedString) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = @nCount
     AND COUNT(*) = @nCount
```

If the variable `@strOrderedString` in the "IN" clause has only one number things work fine.  However, if this string has a list of comma delimited numbers I get a syntax error from execution of the stored procedure (ex:  Syntax error converting the varchar value '1259,2423,2701,2415,2453' to a column of data type int.)

How can I get this query to work?

Comment: why not use inner-subquery in it?

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because SQL does not support a variable to represent a comma delimited list of values for the `IN` clause -- it expects a variable per value, with commas defined in the SQL.  You need to use dynamic SQL, where the SQL is a string concatenated prior to execution, for what you posted to work.

Because you are using SQL Server 2000, you need to use [EXEC/EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to execute dynamic SQL.  `sp_executesql` is SQL Server 2005+.

Comment: dynamic sql is not needed, you can use a tvf to convert the string and use it as a single column list.

Comment: What is a tvf and how would I apply that method?

Comment: TVF = Table Valued Function, I added one to my answer.

Comment: @keithwarren7: That's why "for what you posted to work" is in my answer ;)  TVF, temp table, derived table/inline view -- all are a re-write of the query provided.

Comment: Thanks OMG Ponies.  I did some investigation and it is because I am using the SUM() in the HAVING clause.  Works fine without the SUM() clause, but doesn't get me my results.

Comment: @user774512: Could you update the question to include how the `@nCount` is being populated?

Comment: nCount is populated by a count of the number of values in the CSV list. I was able to get this to work by using dynamic SQL. Due to the HAVING SUM() clause I could not use the TVF route.  Thanks to everyone for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can take your input string and call a table valued function to convert it to a single column table you can nest into the IN clause. Better than using dynamic sql.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertCSVToTable] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(8000) )
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( Id int )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( Id )
        VALUES ( @String )
    END

    RETURN
END
```

This would allow you to still parameterize your list input and avoid dynamic sql, the result would look something like...

```
    SELECT @nDBNum = Num    FROM Num_membersGROUP BY Num  
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Part_No IN (
SELECT Id from dbo.ConvertCSVToTable(@strOrderedString)
) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = @nCount
    AND COUNT(*) = @nCount
```

Comment: You're assuming this is for SQL Server, and the values don't already exist in the database in another table. MySQL also supports the syntax posted.

Comment: fair enough, just the nature of the question made me think his real problem was testing a list of values.

Comment: I don't understand why the OP is dodging the question about what database this is for...

Comment: It is a SQL 2000 database. I am also having problems getting this function to work using the syntax provided in the stored procedure.  I get an "Error 130: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or subquery."  It doesn't like the query in my "HAVING...IN" clause.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the values as an XML parameter to the stored procedure.

```
<Ids>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Id>4</Id>
</Ids>
```

and assign this to a Table Variable;

```
DECLARE @IdsToSearch table(id int);
INSERT INTO @IdsToSearch (id)
SELECT Ids.Id.value('.','INT') FROM @xml.nodes('/Ids/Id') as Ids(Id)
```

and this can then be used in your sql;

```
SELECT @nDBNum = Num
    FROM Num_members
GROUP BY Num
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Part_No IN (SELECT id FROM @IdsToSearch) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = @nCount
     AND COUNT(*) = @nCount
```

This assumes you are using Sql Server 2005/2008